# Неизвестная ошибка при компиляции кода на сервере

Tags: c++, g++

перейду сразу к задаче

Входные данные ([link](https://pp.userapi.com/c850120/v850120057/5d0d5/UXLIK2Tor_k.jpg)):

1. реализовать класс S - класс строк
2. описать конструкторы: по умолчанию, от char, const char*, копирования, реализовать оператор присваивания
3. реализовать операции сложения строк + и +=
4. написать метод length(), возвращающий длину строки и [] для доступа к элементу строки (нумерация с нуля), описать потоковый оператор вывода, описать метод str() возвращающий const char *

---

И написанное решение нужно отправить на тестирофщик, но при компиляции возникает неизвестная ошибка:

[image]

На обычном компиляторе (https://ideone.com/FvSdCC к примеру), все прекрасно работает, но здесь нет. Вот мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
class S{
public:
    char c[99999];

    S(){
        c[0] = 0;
    }

    S(char s){
        c[0] = s;
        c[1] = 0;
    }

    S(const char * s){
        int k = 0;
        while(k > -1)
        {
            if (s[k] != 0)
            {
                c[k] = s[k];
                k+=1;
            }
            else
            {
                c[k] = s[k];
                k = -2;
            }

        }
    }
    S(const S& s){
        for(int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
        {
            c[i] = s.c[i];
        }
    }
    S& operator=(const S& s) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
        {
            c[i] = s.c[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    int length() const{
        int q = 0;

        while(q > -1)
        {
            if (c[q] == 0)
            {
                return q; 
            }
            else
            {
                q++;
            }
        }
    }
    S& operator+=(const S& s1){
        int t = length();
        for(int i = t; i < (t + s1.length()); i++)
        {
            c[i] = s1.c[(i - t)];
        }
        c[t + s1.length()] = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    const S operator+(const S& s1){

        int t = length();
        S tmr(c);

        for(int i = t; i < (t + s1.length()); i++)
        {
            tmr.c[i] = s1.c[(i - t)];
        }
        tmr.c[t + s1.length()] = 0;
        return tmr;
    }
    char operator[](int n){
        return c[n];
    }
    const char operator[](int n) const{
        return c[n];
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const S& value)  
    {  
    os << value.c;  
    return os;  
    }
    const char* str() const {
        return (const char *) c;
    }
};
// это для теста, отсылаю без части main
int main(){
    char a;
    S s("qwerty");
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << s[i] << ' ' << s[2];
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Я новичок, и не до конца понимаю всех тонкостей. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: `char c[99999];` Мда.

Comment: Не всегда память хватит, да и зачем захватить столько памяти для такого простого класса?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибок компиляции в вашем коде не видно, но возможно ваш класс тестировался другим вызывающим кодом? Ага, у вас там в задании ясно написано, что код надо отправлять без функции `main`, т.е. тестирующий код будет совсем другой. Тогда все понятно. Там запросто могут быть ошибки, наведенные вашими ошибками. В частности, ваш оператор `[]` не позволяет ничего записывать в отдельные символы. А тестирующий код, скорее всего, будет это делать.

1. Функция `length()`: что за странный цикл

   ```
   while(q > -1)
   ```

   Но `q` никогда не может стать `<= -1` в этом цикле.
2. Бессмысленная дупликация кода

   ```
   char operator[](int n){
       return c[n];
   }
   const char operator[](int n) const{
       return c[n];
   }
   ```

   Если ваш оператор возвращает свой результат по значению, то зачем понадобились две версии?

   К тому же, как сказано выше, возврат по значению скорее всего и привел к ошибкам компиляции в коде заказчика. Попробуйте сами

   ```
   S s("qwerty");
   s[2] = 'x';
   ```
3. Сложение

   ```
   const S operator+(const S& s1){
   ```

   Этот оператор по уму должен быть `const`. Еще одна потенциальная причина для ошибок компиляции в коде заказчика. Попробуйте сами

   ```
   S s("qwerty");
   s = s + s + s;
   ```
4. В классе, реализованном таким образом (с явным "очень большим" массивом внутри), не нужен явно написанный конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания.

   Кстати, как правильно заметил @AR Hovsepyan в комментариях, ваше ручное копирование массивов, от начала до конца, в ваших реализациях конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания будет в общем случае приводить к чтению неинициализированных элементов массива. А это - неопределенное поведение. Почему вы не останавливаете копирование при достижении конца строки?
5. Зачем здесь сделано явное приведение типа?

   ```
   const char* str() const {
       return (const char *) c;
   }
   ```

Comment: конструктор копирования тоже может вызвать проблему...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Какую именно?

Comment: я имел ввиду что копируется весь массив  с учетом возможного мусора в нем., но не утверждал...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Хм... Логично. Чтение мусора - неопределенное поведение.